# Rails - how to get array index in view using dom_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array attribute in the form and wanting to iterate over this and append each index value to dom id.
I've looked up in the API for use of `dom_id` but I can't locate one that deals with array attribute.

If `dom_id` is not meant for working with array index, is there any other way to get array indexes in the view?

`<div id="ingredient<%= dom_id(?) %>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like following

```
<% array.each_with_index do |arr, index| %>
  <div id="ingredient<%= index %>">
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
<% custom_array.each_with_index  do |item,index| %> 

 <div id="<%= ingredient_#{index} %>">  
       <!--other contents goes here -->
  </div> 

<% end %>
```

Otherwise you can try id = `" ingredient_<%= index>"`